# Solve $ 3 e^x \tan{y} \, dx + \dfrac{2-e^x}{\cos^2{y}} \, dy = 0 $ Stupid error somewhere

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following ODE

$$ 3 e^x \tan{y} \, dx + \dfrac{2-e^x}{\cos^2{y}} \, dy = 0 $$

This is my attempt:

Its form looks like,
$$P(x,y) \, dx + Q(x,y) \, dy = 0$$
so I may be exact or it may accept an integration factor. I have computed:

$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}P(x,y) = \dfrac{3 e^x}{\cos^2{y}} \qquad \qquad \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}Q(x,y) = \dfrac{-e^x}{\cos^2{y}}$$

Unfortunately, these last two terms are not equal, so the equation is not homogeneous. Nevertheless we can find an integration factor because the following expression depends only on $x$

$$\dfrac{1}{Q(x,y)} \left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}P(x,y)-\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}Q(x,y) \right) = \dfrac{4 e^x}{2-e^x} $$

Thus the integration factor is

$$ u(x) = \int \dfrac{4 e^x}{2-e^x}  \, dx = -4 \log{(2-e^x)} $$

Now, we multiply our ODE with $u(x)$ to get an equivalent but exact ODE

$$ u(x) P(x,y) \, dx + u(x) Q(x,y) \, dy = 0$$

My problem is that this last ODE, which should be exact, is not. I have verify my computing with mathematica:

[image]

Where did I mess up?

Comment: The integrating factor should be $\exp \circ u$, not $u$.

Comment: Hate this silly errors... Thanks @GitGud

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integrating factor is is *not* $\displaystyle\int \dfrac{P_y - Q_x}{Q}dx$, as you've written, it is $\exp\left(\displaystyle\int \dfrac{P_y - Q_x}{Q}dx\right) = \dfrac{1}{(2 - e^x)^4}$ (assuming your integration is right).

Comment: That is in fact the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is an easy integral. You can solve it also using, separation of variable,

$3e^x  \tan y  dx  =- (2 – e^x  ) \sec^2y  dy $

Now,

$ \frac{3e^x}{(2 – e^x  )}dx = \frac{\sec^2y}{\tan y}dx $

You can solve this easy integral,
which will yield,

$3\log(e^x-2) = \log|\tan y| + C$

(Credit: Gursheen Kaur,
Meritnation Expert)

Comment: Some used to methods than I didn't notice! Thanks

Comment: @Trollkemada, your welcome.

Comment: @Trollkemada, You should take time to understand your problem by yourself, if it won't work out then only you post it here. You will gain a lot by working out yourself.

Comment: I did take time to understand the problem and try to solve it (I think i showed thay in my question, as I usually do). I just have a final coming so I am solving all ODEs I find and, after solving many with the same method, i didnt noticed this one was solvable easier as you showed.

Comment: @Trollkemada, I am not underestimating you. But you tried. Good luck.